# Was "The Hobbit" book ever abridged?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, childrens-novel

I know the Hobbit was written as a children's book (tale?) and I saw [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124780/did-tolkien-ever-state-that-the-hobbit-was-a-childrens-book) when I searched the site for similar questions to this one. The story itself can certainly be regarded as almost a fairy tale if we are not going too much into details.

This aspect is actually the basis of my question: I want to tell my 4-year old daughter the story of the hobbit, as I'm sure she'll like it if it was made simple enough for her (i.e. if much of the details and even whole parts were omitted to make a simpler story). Of course, I COULD prepare this story on my own, but I was wondering if such a version was ever made (surely not be Tolkien himself, but perhaps as part of the franchise)?

Comment: You're looking for the S. Morgenstern "Good Parts" version ;) ?

Comment: Since it's already regarded as a child's book - you'll probably only find abridged audio or illustrated graphic novels: https://www.amazon.com/Graphic-subtitle-illustrated-fantasy-classic/dp/0345445600

Comment: There are abridged audio versions; https://www.amazon.com/J-R-Tolkien-Hobbit-Abridged/dp/B00HTJSTZS

Comment: Anecdotally, you may just need an illustrated version. I read the full text to my five-year-old son, but he would only pay attention if I was reading from an old edition illustrated with stills from the 1977 animated movie. The handful of Tolkien originals scattered through the edition that came with The History of the Hobbit weren't enough :)

Comment: Peter Jackson found the unabridged three-book set...

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I HAVE read the Hobbit, many times. I am perfectly capable of abridging it myself, but it will obviously take time and may not be as smooth as a professionally made abridged edition, hence my question. Also, as someone pointed out above, it may be a story intended for children, but it is certainly not childish in style (in my opinion, of course), all the more to someone whose first language is NOT English.

Comment: @Don_S If you reveal your first language, maybe someone find a story/audio in this? The Hobbit is a very widespread tale :) At the side: I gave a 8 year old a german radio play of The Hobbit to hear. Some years later the 3 movies about the Hobbit starts in cinema, and the parent of this child were outraged "How could you give our child such a brutal story to hear?" (and I know, they never heard it with their child ... )

Comment: My first language is Hebrew. I did not mention it because I was pretty sure that no one here would be able to help in this regard. There are three translations of the Hobbit to Hebrew (one is particularly interesting because it was made by Israeli air force POWs during their captivity in Egyptian prison some fifty years ago), but they are all full translations of the book, and I'm fairly sure that if there was another Hebrew version I would know about it. At any rate, some translation on my part would be required, but that's not a problem. I was just looking for a good abridged source.

Comment: I have read the story as a teenager and loved it, I am not sure if a 4-year-old girl has the ability to appreciate it, especially for the wealth of characters, except Gandalf and Bilbo, remember the names of all the dwarves and other characters It can be a bit overwhelming. If history manages to get your attention you would give it a beautiful gift. otherwise try again at 7 or 9 years.

Comment: There's hardly any need to differentiate the 12 dwarves aside from Thorin. It doesn't really matter to the story which dwarf served as the lookout, or which dwarf fell asleep in Mirkwood, or who Thorin's nephews are; they are effectively interchangeable.

Comment: It might be somewhat scary for a 4 year old, with orcs, Gollum and Mirkwood etc. My sis read it for me when I was 7 or so and I found it pretty scary then... except I loved it and also ended up a Tolkien nerd later on :)

Comment: Not an answer, but be prepared for a potential response along the lines of "this is boring. there are no girls in it." That was my daughter's response to some (albeit non-Tolkien) things I thought she'd like at around the same age. Nowadays kids have reference points to compare against rather than all the interesting sff and adjacent stuff featuring a male-centric world.

Comment: Maybe four years old is a bit early? I tried to read The Hobbit for my kids when our youngest was about five. That was at bit early for her. Next time, she was seven, I think, and it was magic. Today, she, and her older sister, are serious Tolkien fans :-)

Comment: I even read a comic book adaptation of The Hobbit once.

Answer (score 43):

Yes, several abridged versions have been made available;

- **[The (2009) Highbridge Radio Edit (full cast)](https://highbridgeaudio.com/hobbit.html)**
- **[The (2002) BBC Radio Edit (full cast)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hobbit-Radio-Full-cast-Dramatisation-Collection/dp/056352880X)**
- **[The (1993) Martin Shaw Abridged Audiobook](https://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Hobbit/dp/B002SQD0EW)**
- **[The (1986) BBC Radio Edit (full cast)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit_(radio_series))**
- **[The (1979) Jackanory Radio Edit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hobbit-Jackanory-J-R-R-Tolkien/dp/1471358372/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=V9MWGSVKRECG9RFKH96B)**
- **[The (1964) Princess Magazine Serialisation](http://www.tolkienbooks.net/php/princess.php)** ( http://www.tolkienlibrary.com/tolkien-book-store/PC000007.htm)

The latter is extremely hard to find, but definitely the shortest *written* abridgement available, with the exception of the *see, hear and read-along* novelisation of the [Rankin Bass film of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit_(1977_film)).

You can see it in full below.

Comment: Completionists should not overlook the ill-fated [Hip-Hop Hobbit of the 1980s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrBlb3fnOrA&feature=youtu.be&t=21)...

Comment: @user151841 - Words have failed me.

Comment: deleted alternate ending: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrBlb3fnOrA&feature=youtu.be&t=157

Comment: Has any of these been released in book form?

Comment: @Wade - Not to the best of my knowledge, aside from the novelisation, obvs

Comment: I had the read-along Rankin-Bass as an LP. The illustrations had a huge influence on me early on as an artist (along with the Bakshi LotR calendar illustrations and Alan Lee's contributions to the book *Fairies*

Answer (score 23):

If you're looking for a picture book, there's a [1999 graphic novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=yZSLAAAACAAJ&dq=illustrated%20hobbit&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y) you could look for.  Otherwise there are a various illustrated editions that might be appropriate for reading along with; I found a [list that includes several of them](https://www.thoughtco.com/the-hobbit-for-young-readers-627604).

[image: Cover of Hobbit graphic novel]

Apparently there's even been a [pop-up book](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?610161), though it's not the complete story.

[image: Hobbit pop-up book]

Comment: a John Howe pop-up book! Nice!

Comment: I have the graphic novel and I love it. I may use it, but it is also the full story (even if each picture is worth a thousand words of the original text...). But I'll give it a try.

Comment: Most of the versions in your second link are 300+ pages and almost as long as the original. The 1999 Chuck Dixon version looks most appropriate.

Comment: @Notts90 That was my primary recommendation; the rest were noted mostly for completeness.

Comment: I was also going to recommend the graphic novel by Dixon and Wenzel - really lovely artwork.

Comment: There's a newer version of the graphic novel, which better quality pictures, here: https://www.bookdepository.com/Hobbit-J-R-R-Tolkien/9780261102668?ref=grid-view&qid=1630054436053&sr=1-2, if anyone is interested. Also, can I add a picture of the first page to your answer?

Comment: The cover art of the book in your answer is also a little small; would you consider changing it with this one? https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/lrg/9780/3454/9780345445605.jpg or this one: https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/lrg/9780/2611/9780261102668.jpg